# space between concecutive rows in gnuplot pm3d map

Tags: gnuplot

There are no spaces between 1 and 3; 3 and 5. The 3rd row is not showing in the plot. Here is my Gnuplot :

```
    set terminal jpeg size 1024,768
    set output "test-gnu.jpg"
    set pm3d map corners2color c1
    set palette maxcolors 3
    set palette defined (0 "#FF0000", 1 "#00FF00", 2 "#CCCC00")
    set xlabel "Frame"
    set ylabel ""
    set yrange [   0.000:6.000]
    set xrange [   1.000:5.000]
    splot "-" with pm3d title ""
    1.000     1.000      0
    1.000     3.000      0
    1.000     5.000      0

    2.000     1.000      1
    2.000     3.000      0
    2.000     5.000      1

    3.000     1.000      2
    3.000     3.000      0
    3.000     5.000      2

    4.000     1.000      0
    4.000     3.000      1
    4.000     5.000      2
```

I want white space between 1 and 3; 3 and 5. and also the 3rd-row in the plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, it's not completely clear what you mean, but I'm guessing that you might want the following...
There is no need for `splot` and probably `boxxyerror` does what you want.

```
reset session
$Data <<EOD
1.000     1.000     0
1.000     3.000     0
1.000     5.000     0

2.000     1.000     1
2.000     3.000     0
2.000     5.000     1

3.000     1.000     2
3.000     3.000     0
3.000     5.000     2

4.000     1.000     0
4.000     3.000     1
4.000     5.000     2
EOD

set palette maxcolors 3
set palette defined (0 "#FF0000", 1 "#00FF00", 2 "#CCCC00")
set xlabel "Frame"
set ylabel ""
set yrange [0:6]
set xrange [0:5]
plot $Data u 1:2:(0.5):(0.5):3 with boxxyerror fs solid 1.0 fc palette notitle
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting this kind of error : plot $Data u 1:2:(0.5):(0.5):3 with boxxyerror fs solid 1.0 fc palette notitle
                             ^
"test-1.gnu", line 26: warning: Unrecognized 5 column plot style; resetting to boxerrorbars

Comment: which version of gnuplot are you running? I am on gnuplot 5.2.5

Comment: I am using gnuplot Version 5.0 patchlevel 3. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: The plot style is not known in version 5.0.3. Any reason why you can't update to >5.2?